# Dynamic moving of HTML div depending on window size

Tags: html, css, dynamic, less

In trying to make a div change line if a window is too small to house three divs beside each other. Basically I have three divs beside each other in a container div.

The behaviour right now is that if the windows get small enough, the right div will be moved down with the middle div above it. What I want is that if the window is small enough, the middle div should move below the left div instead.

Skeleton HTML:

```
<div class="level1">
    <div class="level2 clearfix" ng-if="stuff" ng-repeat="stuff">
        <div class="level3-1">
            Stuff with dynamic length depending on ng-repeat
        </div>
        <div class="level3-2">
            Stuff with dynamic length depending on ng-repeat
        </div>
        <div class="level3-3">
            Stuff with dynamic length depending on ng-repeat
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Skeleton LESS CSS:

```
.level1 {
    .level2 {
        .level3-1 {
            float: left;
        }

        .level3-2 {
            float: left;
        }
    }

    .level3-3 {
        float: right;
    }
}
```

So far I've tried to put `level3-1` and `level3-2` inside a div called `testdiv` but that didn't work either:

Skeleton HTML:

```
<div class="level1">
    <div class="level2 clearfix" ng-if="stuff" ng-repeat="stuff">
        <div class="testdiv clearfix">
            <div class="level3-1">
                Stuff with dynamic length depending on ng-repeat
            </div>
            <div class="level3-2">
                Stuff with dynamic length depending on ng-repeat
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="level3-3">
            Stuff with dynamic length depending on ng-repeat
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Skeleton LESS CSS:

```
.level1 {
    .level2 {
        .testdiv {
            display: inline-block;
            word-wrap: break-all;
            /* also tested break-word */
        }

        .level3-1 {
            float: left;
        }

        .level3-2 {
            float: left;
        }
    }

    .level3-3 {
        display: inline-block;
        float: right;
    }
}
```

In the image below, I've tried do show the problem.

[image]

Anyone have a suggestion? Is it possible to do without Bootstrap?

Answer (score 0):

```css
.level1 {
  display:flex;
  flex-direction: row;

  justify-content: space-between;
  max-width: 900px;
  background-color: blue;
   }
.level2 {
  display:flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;

  background-color: red;
}
.level3-1, .level3-2, .level3-3 {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: pink;
  border: 2px black solid;
}
```

```html
   <div class="level1">
       <div class="level2 clearfix" ng-if="stuff" ng-repeat="stuff">
           <div class="level3-1">
               Stuff with dynamic length depending on ng-repeat
           </div>
           <div class="level3-2">
               Stuff with dynamic length depending on ng-repeat
           </div>
       </div>
       <div class="level3-3">
         Stuff with dynamic length depending on ng-repeat
       </div>
   </div>
```

Comment: hope is what you are looking for

Comment: Sorry, it didn't work at all. First, `level3-1` and `level3-2` cannot have fixed width or height. The content comes from the Angular-controller and should be on one line as long as it can. Second, `level3-3` needs to be inside `level2`to be included in the `ng-repeat`.

Also, I realised that on one of the repeats there is a fourth div that should be entirely underneath that row depending on another `ng-if`. And with your solution that div only gets put to the right of `level3-3`.

Comment: i gived a height and width to test it it dosen't mean you have to let it like that but if this is not what you are looking for then i dont know because like i tested it , it makes exectly what you asked but ok if its not that sorry than i can not help you

Comment: I tested it too, and when I only have what you suggested it works fine, the problem is that it doesn't work on the actual page. Unfortunately I have to use skeleton code for the question since it's some secrecy about the actual content.